# Clear child JSP page into default look

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

Below is JSP page

```html
<div id="tabs-7" style="width: 100%;">
 <form:form id="deviceForm" name="" modelAttribute=""  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="inputWidgetContainer">
   <div class="inputWidget">
    <table>
     <tr height="6"></tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="rightalign">
       <input type="radio" id="radio_SampleInput"
        name="xyzRadio" value="sampleInputRadio" checked="checked" 
        onclick="loadXyz()"/>
      </td>
      <td class="leftAlign inputLabel">Sample Input</td>
      <td class="rightalign">
       <input type="radio" id="radio_abc"
        name="sampDtlsRadio" value="abcRadio" 
        onclick="loadabc()">
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
   
  <div id="xyz">
   <jsp:include page='xyz.jsp' />
  </div>
  <div id="abc" class="hide">
   <jsp:include page='abc.jsp' />
  </div>
 </form:form>
</div>
```

In JS file I am hiding div based on user's selection.
Both page have some functionality which changes page's default look, Like row can be added or deleted, Now if user select other radio button and came back to page, default look should be displayed. I don't want to get into undo what user has done, util there is cleaner way to do it.
Currently I am reloading parent page.
Is there any way using ajax call I can request for xyz.jsp page again, so that I don't have to refresh parent page. Or any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's better to use `onchange` rather then `onclick`. Second, combine you radio buttons with the same name (to make it acting like *radio buttons* rather then as a checkboxes). Third, bind your handlers in js code rather then in html. And finally, of course you can load parts via Ajax.

```js
$('[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
  if($('[type="radio"]:checked').val() === 'sampleInputRadio') {
    $('#xyz').load('http://your.serv.er/xyz.jsp');
    loadXyz();
  } else {
    $('#abc').load('http://your.serv.er/abc.jsp');
    loadabc();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="tabs-7" style="width: 100%;">
    <form:form id="deviceForm" name="" modelAttribute=""  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="inputWidgetContainer">
            <div class="inputWidget">
                <table>
                    <tr height="6"></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="rightalign">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio_SampleInput"
                                name="SampleInput" value="sampleInputRadio" checked="checked"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="leftAlign inputLabel">Sample Input</td>
                        <td class="rightalign">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio_abc"
                                name="SampleInput" value="abcRadio">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
            
        <div id="xyz">
            <jsp:include page='xyz.jsp' />
        </div>
        <div id="abc" class="hide">
            <jsp:include page='abc.jsp' />
        </div>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

P.S. Since I don't know what your original handler do, I just call its after load .jsp requests but maybe it is unnecessary.